# How to merge records with its relevant in different spelling Power BI

Tags: database, powerbi, dax

I have a table with customer_name the same column has the name of the customer and location, some records customer name including "s" at end of customer name.
is there any way to merge these kind of records to its relative? 
I don't want to effect database, I need to correct the data in Power BI for reporting.

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
| Customer_name | QTY     | U_price | amount  | Item_No   |
-----------------------------------------------------------
| xxx(London)   | 2       | 20.00   | 40.00   |   5       |
-----------------------------------------------------------
| xxx(Brisbane) | 4       | 20.00   | 80.00   |   5       |
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

so it should be

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
| Customer_name | QTY     | U_price | amount  | Item_no   |
-----------------------------------------------------------
| xxx           | 6       | 20.00   | 120.00  |     5     |
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Can you put into words the logic that you would apply? If it is logical, it can be created with a formula, be it DAX or Power Query. If you can't describe the logic and identifying names is done with human intelligence only, then there is not much of a chance. One example for logic would be "compare only what's before the ( sign". Can you word rules like that?

Comment: I have already updated

Comment: So, where do you explain the logic??? You have not addressed that at all. Just ONE example of ONE customer -- does that cover ALL your possible customer name variations? In that case, take the first three characters, right? `xxx` will be the result. Or not? If not, what other logic is there to apply? I'm trying to help you here, but I need more information.

Comment: My question was about the possibility, and if there is an example.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that can be done in Power BI. You only need to apply the logic for identifying the names that belong together.

Comment: do you mean I have to write some logic? or dose power bi has some intelligent features to detect this kind of data ?

Comment: @MSTQNB Power BI doesn't magically know how you want things grouped and you haven't explained what kind of variations you want to be merged. Depending on the variations, it could be very simple or next to impossible.

Comment: You need to be able to express the logic in words. That's what I was trying to get across above. If you can explain the logic, chances are that it's possible to write a formula to extract the desired data for grouping. We can help, but your input is required.